# Cómo abrir Modal en vez de Redireccionar si un registro no se puede borrar en la BD

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Estoy trabajando con PHP y Bootstrap, mostrando una clásica tabla con datos, para este ejemplo son registros de **MARCAS** cuya última columna son los botones EDITAR y ELIMINAR, esto funciona, pero siempre recarga (redirecciona) para hacer el trabajo que debe hacer, por ejemplo (y este es mi problema específico):

Si quiero ELIMINAR un registro clickeo ELIMINAR y va desde **marcas-view.php** (donde está la tabla) a **marcas-actions.php** pasando el ID por $_GET y en **marcas-actions.php** compruebo si el registro es "eliminable" preguntándole a **marcas-data.php** (que es como el objeto en si), si es eliminable llamo nuevamente a **marcas-data.php** y lo elimina y entonces recarga la página completa, y si no es "eliminable" por X o Y razón no llama a marcas-data.php pero igual recarga la página **marcas-view.php** pero lo hace para mostrar un aviso que puse sobre la tabla.

Lo que quiero es que si NO es "eliminable" en vez de recargar para mostrar el aviso sobre la tabla, me muestre un Modal diciendo que no se pudo.

El problema es que he tratado pero nunca usé Modals y por más que aplico ejemplos no me resulta y creo que lo mejor es usar mi propio código para obtener el resultado.

Acá dejo los códigos:

**marcas-view.php**

```
<div class="box-body"> 
    <table class="table table-bordered datatable table-hover">
        <thead>     
            <th></th>
        </thead>
        <?php
            foreach($marcas_array as $temp_marca)
            {
            ?>
            <tr>                
                <td style="width:130px;">                                       
                    <?php if($temp_marca->id > 0):?>
                    <a href="index.php?view=brands&opt=edit&id=<?php echo $temp_marca->id;?>" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Editar</a>
                    <a href="index.php?action=brands&opt=del&id=<?php echo $temp_marca->id;?>&name=<?php echo $temp_marca->name;?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Eliminar</a>
                    <?php endif; ?>                                     
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php                                   
            }                               
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

**marcas-actions.php**

```
<?php>
    else if(isset($_GET["opt"]) && $_GET["opt"]=="del")
    {
        if($_GET["id"] > 0)
        {
            $marca = marcas-data::getById($_GET["id"]);
            if($marca->noEliminable())
            {   
                $titulo     = base64_encode("Advertencia!");
                $mensaje    = base64_encode("No puede eliminar la marca " . $marca->name . " mientras esté en uso.");
                Core::redir("./index.php?view=brands&opt=all&msgtext=" . $mensaje . "&msgtitle=" . $titulo . "&msgtype=danger&msgicon=ban");
            }
            else 
            {
                $marca->del();
                $titulo     = base64_encode("Resultado");
                $mensaje    = base64_encode("Se eliminó " . $marca->name . " de la lista de marcas.");
                Core::redir("./index.php?view=brands&opt=all&msgtext=" . $mensaje . "&msgtitle=" . $titulo . "&msgtype=success&msgicon=check"); 
            }   
        }
        else 
        {
            $titulo     = base64_encode("Información");
            $mensaje    = base64_encode("No puede eliminar la marca genérica porque es un atributo reservado de administración.");
            Core::redir("./index.php?view=brands&opt=all&msgtext=" . $mensaje . "&msgtitle=" . $titulo . "&msgtype=info&msgicon=cog"); 
        }
    }

?>
```

**marcas-data.php**

```
<?php>
    public function noEliminable()
    {
        return Executor::getCount("select count(*) from product where marca_id=$this->id")[0] > 0;
    }

    public function del()
    {
        $sql = "select count(*) from product where marca_id=$this->id";
        $res = Executor::getCount($sql);

        if($res[0] > 0)
        {
            Core::alert("No puede borrar la marca \'" . $this->name . "\' mientras haya productos de esa marca registrados.");
        }
        else 
        {
            $sql = "delete from marcas where id=$this->id";
            Executor::doit($sql);
        }
    }       
?>
```

Cualquier ayuda sobre COMO mostrar el Modal cuando NO pueda borrar el registro se agradecerá.

Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

> amigo para hacer lo que tienes en mente necesitas trabajar ya sea con js o jquey >haces uso de ajax y el response de ese texto lo puedes evaluar y disparar el modal >que quieres, mi pregunta solo estas trabajando con php y Bootstrap?
>   te dejo un ejemplo con jquery

```
// al hacer click en el boton con la clase detele, se ejecuta una funcion anonima
    $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
            var user_id = $(this).attr("id"); // capturamos el id del objeto que queremos eliminar ejemplo id='7' capturamos ese 7.
            if(confirm("Seguro quieres eliminar este usuario?"))// como es para eliminar mostramos esta ventana para no eliminar algo que no queremos
            {
                $.ajax({
                        url:"controller/eliminar_usuario.php", //a donde enviamos el id
                        method:"POST",// el metodo sea GET o POST
                        data:{user_id:user_id}, // la informacion para capturar seria $_POST['user_id'];
                    success:function(data){    // siempre que se envia la informacion sin ningun error se ejecuta esta funcion
        // evalúas si es eliminable o no capturando la data y viendo si es true o false
         if(data == false){
        //haces el modal visible
        $('#tumodal').modal('show');  // el modal ya tiene que estar creado para poder mostrarlo.
        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                return false;   
            }
    });
```

Comment: Si, solo estoy con PHP y Bootstrap pero tengo las librerías JS incluídas, ese código que incluyes lo entiendo mas o menos, creo que por ahí va la solución, solo que necesito que esté explicado paso a paso para poder entender la lógica porque con JS no tengo mucha práctica y me cuesta un poco aún asociar a qué se refiere cada cosa del código.
Gracias :)